# Expand numeric vector elements with constant (natural number)

Tags: r, vector, integer

Given a vector `v <- c(1, 10, 22)` and a constant natural number say `c <- 3` how can I expand `v` with integers in a window of size `c`. So the vector would become `w` (i.e. 1 is expanded three integers to each side, the integers -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4) :

```
> w
 [1] -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

Comment: `c(t(sapply(-3:3, \`+\`, v)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sapply`

```
c(sapply(v, function(x) (x-c):(x+c)))
#[1] -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

---

Or `Map`

```
unlist( Map(`:`, v-c, v+c))
```

Comment: Thats wonderful and concise. In the 2nd, you apply the function `:` to the two arguments (the limits of my range) ?

Comment: @user3375672  `Map` takes corresponding elements from the vectors `v-c` and `v+c` and gives it to `:` to get the sequence

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is

```
c(t(sapply(-c:c, `+`, v)))
#[1] -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

And this is more efficient for large v-vectors because the sapply loop iterates only over `-c:c` instead of every element of `v`. A simple comparison shows this:

```
set.seed(1)
v <- sample(1e6)
system.time(unlist( Map(`:`, v-c, v+c)))              # akrun 1
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      1.518       0.067       1.595 
system.time(c(sapply(v, function(x) (x-c):(x+c))))    # akrun 2
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      1.564       0.074       1.652 
system.time(c(t(sapply(-c:c, '+', v))))               # docendo
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      0.082       0.024       0.106 
system.time(c(mapply(seq, v-c, v+c)))                 # 989
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      7.132       0.123       7.292
```

Comment: This is even faster : `unlist(lapply(-c:c, '+', v))`

Comment: @digEmAll, true, but not in order, (otherwise you wouldn't need `t` in my approach either)

Comment: @docendo discimus , could u explain why _transposing_ reduces the evaluation time ?

Comment: @ParthChaudhary, it's not the transposing that reduces evaluation time. Please read my answer again - I mentioned what (presumably) reduces the run time

Comment: Oh, got it..because of iteration over -c:c rather than every element!

Answer (score 2):

Using `mapply`:

```
c(mapply(seq, v-c, v+c))

#[1] -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another very fast option (maybe not very elegant though...) :

```
w <- rep.int(v, rep(c*2+1,length(v))) + (-c:c)
```

Benchmark :

```
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(1)
v <- sample(1e6)

c <- 3
microbenchmark(times=30,
               docendo =c(t(sapply(-c:c, '+', v))),
               digemall=rep.int(v, rep(c*2+1,length(v))) + (-c:c)
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
#   docendo 81.04337 82.50133 100.7718 83.78972 99.89731 169.38202    30
#  digemall 28.57355 30.28533  37.0091 31.01103 32.18491  90.90412    30

c <- 20
microbenchmark(times=30,
               docendo =c(t(sapply(-c:c, '+', v))),
               digemall=rep.int(v, rep(c*2+1,length(v))) + (-c:c)
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#   docendo 581.9529 626.4765 673.2964 663.0599 713.8367 787.1848    30
#  digemall 174.3748 177.2943 198.9419 180.0702 200.0904 319.6669    30
```